# Linear Superposition Principle - Origin of interference term

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, superposition

[image]

How do you from 2.8 to 2.10 ? I'm confused :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\Psi|^2=\Psi^*\Psi=(c_1^*\Psi_1^* + c_2^*\Psi_2^*)(c_1\Psi_1 + c_2\Psi_2)=c_1^*\Psi_2^*c_1\Psi_1+c_2^*\Psi^*c_2\Psi_2 + c_1^*\Psi_1^*c_2\Psi_2 + c_1\Psi_1c_2^*\Psi_2^* = |c_1\Psi_1|^2+|c_2\Psi_2|^2 + c_1\Psi_1c_2^*\Psi_2^* + (c_1\Psi_1c_2^*\Psi_2^*)^* = |c_1\Psi_1|^2+|c_2\Psi_2|^2 + 2Re(c_1\Psi_1c_2^*\Psi_2^*)$

Than substituting 2.9, you get 2.10.

Comment: This is perfect and I have no idea how I didn't see this. I'm still recovering from some massive jet lag so I guess I can be excused ! Thanks though ! Would upvote but I lack the rep to do so.